# Why do my thread-safe code not work?

Tags: c, thread-safety

I am trying to create a thread-safe delete function for a binary search tree. The code below is my result, but it causes the program to deadlock. What is going wrong with the locks? I have tried to comment some locks but that causes segfault instead...

```
struct bst_node {
    void* data;
    pthread_mutex_t mut;
    struct bst_node* left;
    struct bst_node* right;
};

static void node_del(struct bst_node** node) {

pthread_mutex_lock(&(*node)->mut);

struct bst_node* old_node = *node;

if(((*node)->left == NULL) && ((*node)->right == NULL)) {
    *node = NULL;
    free_node(old_node);

} else if ((*node)->left == NULL) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&((*node)->right->mut));
    *node = (*node)->right;
    free_node(old_node);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(*node)->mut);

} else if ((*node)->right == NULL) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&((*node)->left->mut));
    *node = (*node)->left;
    free_node(old_node);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(*node)->mut);

} else {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&((*node)->left->mut));

    struct bst_node** pred = &(*node)->left;
    while ((*pred)->right != NULL) {

        pthread_mutex_lock(&(*pred)->right->mut);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(*pred)->mut);
        pred = &(*pred)->right;
    }

    void* temp = (*pred)->data;
    (*pred)->data = (*node)->data;
    (*node)->data = temp;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(*pred)->mut);

    node_del(pred);
}

}
```

Note that I have initalized the node and the lock "mut" in another function.

Comment: Your call to `free_node()` is not self-evidently locked.  You might have the lock in the function — we can't tell from here.

Comment: Suppose thread `t1` has locked the mutex of node `n1`. Now suppose thread `t2` has locked the mutex of node `n2`. Now, what if `t1` try to access `n2` - as its mutex is locked, it will start waiting. Meanwhile, `t2` wants to use `n1`, but it's locked by `t1`. So, deadlock.

Comment: It seems like there are other issues, too, but the one in my prev comment is a potential deadlock, too. Be careful with that situation.

Answer (score 0):

The first `pthread_mutex_lock(&(*node)->mut)` without `pthread_mutex_unlock`. I think this is the root cause of your deadlock.